# How can I find out if my GNU C library is thread-safe?

Tags: c, matlab, thread-safety, mex

I'm currently [receiving weird segmentation violations when runnning a MATLAB MEX file in paralle](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35754-segmentation-faults-when-running-mex-files-in-parallel)l.

After a lot of debugging, I'm 99% sure that the segmentation violation has nothing to do with the MEX file itself but with the fact that I'm running it in parallel.

One possible reason for the segmentation violations that was suggested is that the C library functions "malloc" and "free" may not be thread-safe. Is this really a possibility? And is there any way that I can make sure?

I compiled the MEX file using the "GNU C 2.14.90 development" C Library - so I guess I'm looking for a website where this is distributed / these types of questions are answered.

Comment: Never heard that on platforms that provide threading, the GNU C library implementation of `malloc` and `free` would not be thread safe. Millions of programmers use this every day, your error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for this. That's what I thought as well. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Are you only parallelizing with Matlab's parallel constructs, parfor and the like, or do you have parallel code in the mex file, like an openMP parallel section?

Comment: What's the result of `ulimit -s` at the shell prompt?

Comment: mex can have some specific requirements vis-a-vis C files, and you should be implementing mxAlloc instead of malloc and mxFree instead of free. This is important as Matlab lives in its own space. "[To deallocate heap space, MATLAB applications in C ***should always call*** mxFree rather than the ANSI C free function.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/mxfree.html)"

Comment: @Rasman I was considering this, but it turns out that mxAlloc and mxFree are not thread-safe whereas malloc and free are.

Comment: @Sevenless I'm parallelizing using MATLAB constructs

Comment: mex in general isn't [thread safe](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-V3B5T/index.html?solution=1-V3B5T). So you're problem may be much bigger then that. Try to execute some of your code outside a parallel construct